# Best way to respond to a request for CV after graduation

Tags: cv, email

I did a summer internship in an industry for 9 week. It was a great experience and my supervisor was a very formal and professional lady. She rarely smiled but appreciated my work every now and then. On my last day, she asked about my graduation date and I told her it’s just 6 months away as it was my last semester. 
She responded: "Send me your CV when you graduate.”

Now I want to write to her. How do I begin with that? It’s been 6 months and there’s no particular opening in that department. Should I send my CV in the first mail itself? If so should I also include a cover letter? What's the best way to introduce myself?

Comment: You’re overthinking this. She said to send her your CV, so absolutely send her your CV. Not much ambiguity here... as for the other details, I like @JoshuaZ’s suggested formulation.

Comment: Just a comment to your (deleted) update: Just send a "thank you very much"mail. All is fine now.

Answer (score 24):

Just send a note with 1 to 3 **short** paragraphs.

1. Remind her of the work you did together (you are colleagues, brothers in arms).
2. Give her an update on what you have done during the last 6 months (e.g. papers you published, your thesis, courses you took).
3. Let her know what job options you are looking at (even prospects). Ask her for any advice on your prospects and whether she knows of any opportunity at her place or elsewhere.
4. Thank her for the time together and how it benefited you.

And yes, include the CV.

Comment: While this is a good basis for a note, IMO it lacks mentioning that you are sending this per the recipient's request for the information. If this note/CV ends up going through someone that is filtering such information for the recipient, it's important for it to be clear that the CV that's being provided was actually requested, rather than just coming out of the blue (regardless of mentioning that there's already an established working relationship). Information that's been requested has a *far* better chance of sailing quickly through any human filtering that's being done on CVs.

Answer (score 17):

Something like : "Dear Dr. ____, I hope this email finds you well. You asked me to send you a copy of my CV when I graduated; please find it attached. I remain interested in _____ and working at _____ if possible.

Sincerely/Best regards (whichever sounds better),

NAME"

Simple and to the point.

Comment: Unfortunately, this phrasing starts off making it sound like OP is doing this burdensome thing as a favor to the manager.  Better would be "Thank you for your interest in my CV" or "Thank you for inviting me to submit a CV", both of which affirm the request and that OP values the opportunity.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's a good point. That is a better wording.

Answer (score 5):

You should thank her for the opportunity to work with her in the past and mention the project if it has a name. Tell  her you've now graduated and are sending the CV as per her request.

Make the letter fairly broad. While she may not be able to hire you directly, she may want to promote you to others or aid you in some other way.

You could also mention your current/future plans, but don't make it too long or wordy. Include contact information.