# best words to respond to a request for cv after graduation

Tags: cv, email, internship, graduation

Last summer I did an internship in an industry for 9 weeks. It was a great experience and my supervisor was a very formal and professional lady. On my last day, she asked about my graduation date and I told her it’s just 6 months away as it was my last semester. She responded: "Send me your CV when you graduate.”

I sent her a mail today and got this reply.

“Good to see your email and glad to know that you have achieved an important milestone. 
Congratulations on your graduation.
Your CV has been received and shall be forwarded to HR.

All the best for your future endeavors.”

What should be my response now? I don’t wanna sound immature  or unprofessional. 
I was thinking about a thank you or something but I don’t know  if that would be appropriate.

Comment: _Did I play it right?_ What were you trying to achieve? _What should be my response now?_ You should probably just wait.

Comment: Sorry, wrong choice of words I guess. I was thinking about a thank you or something but I don’t know if that would be appropriate.

Comment: This looks related to [an earlier question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/122050/best-way-to-respond-to-a-request-for-cv-after-graduation?rq=1) but through a new account, with an identical username. Perhaps you should contact the SE team and request for an account merger. :)

Comment: Nope, I disagree. It isn't a duplicate, but rather a follow-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can send her a note thanking her for both her past help and continued support. It should be short and not contain questions or such that require a reply.

Then you wait.

Comment: ‘Thank you for your past help and continued support. It has truly been an inspiration to work with you.’ 

Will this be okay?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be appropriate to thank her.  Send a short e-mail:

> Thank you.